# Предложение заблокировать доступ к ruSO конкретному участнику (4+ аккаунта, рецидивист)

Tags: предложение, блокировка

Предлагаю сделать что-нибудь с вредоносным участником [Yurii Didyk](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/391703/yurii-didyk) / [Trash Mail](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/452827/trash-mail) / [Ken Barbies](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/453065/ken-barbies) / [Epic Game](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/453138/epic-game) / ... (явно одно и то же лицо).

Хоть это и жестоко, предлагаю забанить: т.к. все вопросы участника низкокачественные, и он полностью игнорирует призывы следовать правилам, продолжая множить аккаунты и повторяя одни и те же нарушения (в отношении качества вопросов: вопросы-ссылки и невнятное описание) раз за разом.
Тревогу о возможном обходе блокировки участником отправлял 2 дня назад в порядке эксперимента - она еще на рассмотрении.

Альтернативные решения приветствуются, но к бинайсу просьба не взывать (с политикой отношения к участникам уже ознакомлен, понимаю что лучше представить "я в домике" поясняя какие правки надо внести, или жать закрытие раз за разом - но резервов нейтралитета/дисциплины на это уже не хватает. Если сообщество неявно поощряет данное явление по каким-то своим причинам, прошу просто закрыть этот вопрос).

Comment: Призывы следовать правилам были в ныне удаленном комментарии [к этому вопросу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1307853/288409), если верно помню - к сожалению, не заскринил. _//То, почему с подозрительной частотой пропадают комменты об улучшениях вопросов, это уже отдельная тема (которую здесь обсуждать будет неуместно)._

Comment: На SO нет нормального способа забанить участника - пользователь может создавать аккаунты снова и снова, продолжать задавать некачественные вопросы - и модераторы ничего с этим не могут поделать

Comment: Рекорд, на моей памяти, - 23 аккаунта на протяжении  3 лет и сотни вопросов от одного и того же человека :)

Comment: @PashaPash, спасибо за объяснение. Этот вопрос лучше удалить, правильно понимаю? (думаю что тут вряд ли будут предложены альтернативы бану, т.к. они вроде отсутствуют. Разве что расширение браузерное писать для скрытия непотребщины)

Comment: И да, некоторые комментарии могут удалиться автоматом по первой же тревоге, если в них есть слова из стоплиста (в котором вроде есть слово «вопрос»). Так что не удивляйтесь, если ваши комменты пропадают - их вполне может незаметно сносить сам автор вопроса :))

Comment: Вопрос хороший, проблема же есть - просто решения нет :)

Comment: Автоматика не успевает накладывать question ban, при бане одного просто создаётся новый. Система не рассчитана на подобный сценарий. Можно отслеживать цепочки клонов, в т.ч. и по тексту сообщений, но автоматики тут никакой нет. Модераторы имеют права банить учётки, но процесс бана участников создающих новые учётки выстроен намного хуже.

Comment: @AK, да, технические ограничения понятны. И вряд ли когда-нибудь появится бан голосованием (даже временный), т.к. клоноводы его тут же используют в своих интересах (да и вообще, то чего нет на ориг.SO априори не имеет шансов к реализации). Ситуация похоже безвыходная. Кстати, тем временем, в метке js завелся еще один клоновод... рано или поздно, такое поведение популяризуют :winter-is-coming.jpg: